# how to get column names in PDO error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

when I use PDO errorInfo

I get this :

```
Array ( 
[0] => 23000
[1] => 1062
[2] => Duplicate entry 'zzz@zzz.net' for key 'email'
)
```

but I wanna get only column name > 'email' and 1062 for error code to echo :

> this email zzz@zzz.net already registered

because I use email or phone or username for registration

Comment: You should not use errors to drive your code. Use validation instead. Then this error can only happen on race conditions which will be very rare and imho just need an "please try again" message.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the only way of doing it is to use regular expression. You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to search and replace the text.

```
list(, $code, $message) = $dbh->errorInfo();
// check if duplicate error
if ($code === 1062) {
    echo preg_replace_callback("/^Duplicate entry '(.*)' for key '(.*)'$/", function ($m) {
       return sprintf("this %s %s already registered", $m[2], $m[1]);
    }, $message);
    // this email zzz@zzz.net already registered
}
```

Comment: good way , but all mysql and pdo versions will result same error text ?

Comment: That I do not know. `$message` is a driver-specific error message, so I am assuming there will be variations.